# Postgres optimization checklist for large datasets

Tags: database-design, scalability, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.5

We are using Postgres 9.3 (Planning to upgrade to 9.5). Wanted to know if there is some checklist available for optimizing the Postgresql server.

I am looking for optimization at following level:

1. Postgres db config parameter level
2. Best practices from database point of view (Tables & Queries)

I am having customer table of ***50 million*** records and transaction table has ***2.4 billion*** records.

**Index is as follows (Both the table has no partitions) :**

> Customer Master: CustomerId and EnrolledDate (Single Index)
>
> Transaction : CustomerId and InvoiceDate (Single Index)

All the expected report/output is using the above 2 tables.

The server specs is as follows:

- OS: Ubunutu 14.04 LTS
- CPU: 16 CPU @ 2.4Ghz
- RAM: 64 GB
- Storage: 1500 GB
- Applications:  PostgreSQL 9.3 (Planning to upgrade to 9.5)

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization and http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Comment: I checked the link ... But apart from that anything specific you may want us to check it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You won't ever find such a checklist because as data grows, the performance bottle necks depend very much on the specific read and write patterns of your application.

Now, the largest PostgreSQL db I have worked with is 10TB in size and growing fast.  Our challenges are read/write scaling and managing these requires a close eye on the actual problems and an understanding of how things work on a low level.

If the number of rows is your primary concern then your checklist boils down to:

1. Enough buffers and ram to store all relevant indexes.
2. a run through every sort of frequent query and look at what indexes might need to be added to make it fast.

Be warned that frequent updates at the head of an index can have unpleasant side effects and a query plan will not tell you everything.  But it is where to start.